# Python Turtle compare colour

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

my problem is I wanted to compare the Turtle colour but apparently there is a failure:

```
>>> turtle.color("green")

>>> turtle.color()

('green', 'green')

>>> turtle.color==("green")

False

>>> turtle.color==('green', 'green')

False
```

I already tried really many options of syntax but there was always the same output.
I hope you can help me out here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *call* the `color()` function:

```
turtle.color() == ('green', 'green')
```

otherwise you are trying to compare the function object itself.

Comment: Thank you so much! BTW: Why is that green twice are there two colours?

Comment: See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.color); they are the pen and fill colors, respectively.